# IONIC 3 Visualization Issue ion-content Android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

With just ion-content element on a page it shows a square in the top left-hand corner only in Android and I don't know why.

What is that little grey square?

My package's versions

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.12
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.5.3
```

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the gray square is the y-axis scrollbar of ion-content scroll content element.

This works for me.

```
scroll-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Please refer to: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/6416